How to login with password but without pressing enter button?
I used Windows 10, there was a convenient function for loging in system. If password matches, the login occurs automaticaly without pressing the enter button. How to implement such an automatic login in Kubuntu 24.04 LTS? I have only one user, this is my home PC.
Thanks!

This question is similar to: Use pin code to login instead of long password 20.04. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Windows uses PIN for this feature. PIN can be just 4 or 6 numbers or longer alphanumeric password.

Thanks, but this doesn't solve my problem. In the question I wrote that I want autologin after entering the correct password. Now I enter the password, then press enter, then log in. Yes, it is similar to PIN in Windows, but only in that it does not require pressing enter. I do not want to change the password, make it shorter, etc.
I think my question clearly states the essence of the problem.

The answer is no, as it was in the previous question.
